# Syntax for BasedOn in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know how to extend a style in XAML, i.e. for a TextBlock:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
```

But if the control has a prefix, it throws an exception:

```
BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Foo:MyControl}}"
```

What is the right syntax?

Comment: The syntax is correct. What exception are you getting?

Comment: I get a XamlParseException.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the error in the Style itself.

Comment: Would have been great to share your solution bro. I'm having the same issue.